# How to show Loading message instantly while using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Below is my Ajax code I have made using jQuery Ajax method.

```
$(".loading_msg").show();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit_ops.php?action=submit_form",
    data: $( "#frmMyForm" ).serialize(),
    success: function(result){
        if(result=='Success'){
            $("#msgContainer").html('<div style="color:#3CA322;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;padding:10px;">Thank you.</div>');
            $("#msgContainer").fadeIn();
        }
        else{
            $("#msgContainer").html('<div style="color:red;font-size:12px;padding:10px;">' + result + '</div>');
            $("#msgContainer").fadeIn();
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        //console.log('error');
    },
    complete: function(){
        //console.log('complete');
        $(".loading_msg").hide();
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
    }

});
```

So the logic is, whenever the Ajax request is about to made,

1. the .login_msg container is displayed first
2. then ajax call made
3. and when it is completed, again the .loading_msg is hidden.

Now the problem, it is not working smoothly as it should be. So when the ajax call is made, the browser hangs for a seconds but it doesn't show the loading message. But when the request is completed, the login message appears like for half a second and then it goes away as I have set it hidden on request completion.

**So I want that the .login_msg should be shown before the request is made.**

Any suggestions for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try using `beforeSend` and `complete` settings of `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit_ops.php?action=submit_form",
    data: $( "#frmMyForm" ).serialize(),
    beforeSend:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").show();
        }
    complete:function(){
             $(".loading_msg").hide();
        }

    ....
    ....
});
```

Comment: try serializing form before showing loading: `var d=$( "#frmMyForm" ).serialize();` and then set data form this vairable in `$.ajax` like `data:d,` I think it is causing the browser to hang and delay showing of loading image. remember when something heavy is going on the loading animation might skip or not be drawn immediately after `show()` is called.

Comment: Found the issue. I was using async:false; and it was causing the issue. now it is solved as I removed that setting. Thanks for the efforts @TheVillageIdiot